# Get "Value" property in IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, igrouping

I have a data structure like

```
public DespatchGroup(DateTime despatchDate, List<Products> products);
```

And I am trying to do...

```
var list = new List<DespatchGroup>();

foreach (var group in dc.GetDespatchedProducts().GroupBy(i => i.DespatchDate))
{
    // group.Values is not correct... how do I write this?
    list.Add(new DespatchGroup(group.Key, group.Values);
}
```

I'm obviously not understanding `IGrouping` as I can't see how to actually get to the data records within the group!

Comment: The edit [(Rev2)](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4804477/2) wasn't very constructive as it doesn't match any of the answers.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The group implements `IEnumerable<T>` - In the *general* case, just call `foreach` over the `group`. In *this* case, since you need a `List<T>`:

```
list.Add(new DespatchGroup(group.Key, group.ToList());
```

Comment: So basically if we are following the essence of the question `value` is comparable to `ToList()` only there is more of an overhead there to convert it to a list as opposed to just pulling out a value

Comment: @CodeBlend there's more overhead because they want a list. If there was a `Values` property like they imagined then they'd have to do `group.Values.ToList()`. Conversely if they accepted any enumerable instead of a list then `new DespatchGroup(group.Key, group)` would work. The overhead is from the definition of `DespachGroup` not from the way IGrouping works.

Answer (score 46):

There's no `Values` property or similar because the `IGrouping<T>` itself *is* the `IEnumerable<T>` sequence of values. All you need to do in this case is convert that sequence to a list:

```
list.Add(new DespatchGroup(group.Key, group.ToList());
```

Comment: We may also convert to an IEnumerable if we wish: `group.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq While that is possible it is a bit redundant as IGrouping already is derived from IEnumerable. It will work in most places you would use IEnumerable without needing any kind of explicit casting/converting.

Answer (score 41):

For any selected group,you could call

```
var selectedGroupValues=selectedGroup.SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unlike `.Select` which will return an IGrouping<> again, `.SelectMany` will return an IEnumerable of the groupped values' type, which is what I was after.

Comment: I'd say only use this when there are (potentially) multiple groups selected. (aka `IEnumerable<IGrouping<key,DespatchGroup>>`). Otherwise, use `toList()`, or simply cast it to `IEnumerable<DespatchGroup>`.

Answer (score 27):

Just a related tip - since, as the other answers have said, the grouping is an IEnumerable, if you need to access a specific index you can use `group.ElementAt(i)`.

This is probably obvious to a lot of people but hopefully it will help a few!